# I am trying to detect urls from text using java but not receiving proper one

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```java
import com.linkedin.urls.detection.UrlDetector;
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;

boolean isValidURL(String url) {
    if (urlValidator == null) {
        System.out.println("Creating new URL Validator");
        urlValidator = new UrlValidator(UrlValidator.ALLOW_2_SLASHES + UrlValidator.ALLOW_ALL_SCHEMES);
    }
    return urlValidator.isValid(url) || urlValidator.isValid("http://" + url);
}

// Extract and return valid URL from whole SMS text.
private List<String> getURLFromSMSText(String smsTextMessage) {
    // smsTextMessage = "PARADISE HALEEM @Rs.249 & 1 KG FAMILY PACK @Rs.699. Your Favourite " +
    // "1 KG PARADISE Nizami Chicken Biryani @Rs.279 " +
    // "in Hyderabad Valid in Take Away " +
    // "- http://google/element8441876860/promethium/7893214560.com " + " bit.ly/653282 " +
    // "sdfsdfsf http://google/googlet.com 7893214560.com"
    String validUrl = null;
    String tempUrl = null;
    List<String> urlsInSms = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        UrlDetector parser = new UrlDetector(smsTextMessage, UrlDetectorOptions.Default);
        List<Url> found = parser.detect();
        if (found != null && found.size() > 0) {
            for (Url url : found) {
                tempUrl = url.getOriginalUrl();
                if (tempUrl != null && isValidURL(tempUrl)) {
                    System.out.println("Valid Original URL: " + url.getOriginalUrl());
                    System.out.println("Scheme: " + url.getScheme());
                    System.out.println("Host: " + url.getHost());
                    System.out.println("Path: " + url.getPath());
                    urlsInSms.add(tempUrl);
                    /*validUrl = tempUrl;
                    break;*/
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Retrived Url is In-Valid (" + url.getOriginalUrl() + ")");
                    if (DebugConfig.getInstance().isDebugEnable()) {
                        log.error("Retrived Url is In-Valid (" + url.getOriginalUrl() + ")");
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (DebugConfig.getInstance().isDebugEnable())
                log.error("No Matching URL present in SMS (" + smsTextMessage + ")");
        }
    } catch (Exception ue) {
        if (DebugConfig.getInstance().isDebugEnable())
            log.error("Exception in Url Detection\r\n");
    }
    return urlsInSms;
}
```

with above code am getting **properly** when i have urls as
**bit.ly/653282**
and **http://google.com**

but it is **not detecting properly** when urls like

**http://google/element8441876860/promethium/7893214560.com**

giving as **7893214560.com**

i want to detect this also
http://google/element8441876860/promethium/7893214560.com

Comment: what `UrlDetector` and `UrlValidator` do you use exactly?

Comment: @cyberbrain am using apache UrlValidator
org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;

Comment: @cyberbrain
the UrlDetector is not extracting properly
using LinkedIn detector
com.linkedin.urls.detection.UrlDetector;

Comment: I believe the issue is with a false positive with the URL validator.  
 http://google/element8441876860/promethium/7893214560.com is not a valid url

Comment: You could try to add a UrlDetectorOption `ALLOW_SINGLE_LEVEL_DOMAIN`